# IPython inserting text without code

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

Im taking a stats course with Python and IPython notebook files for the course have alot of text.
How is the text incorporated into an IPython notebook file without defining the text in python code for a string or HTML?
For example where its highlighted yellow below "Ill start with the data from the BRFSS again"

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see your question and am editing my answer

You'll change the settings from "code" to "markdown":

[image]

After changing the settings from "code" to "markdown" at the top of your notebook, you'll simply type whatever you want to type and press shift + enter.

Comment: Oh ok, I know how to do that but how did the creator insert the text without without using the tag `#commented` ...?

Comment: I edited my answer. You can go to the top of the notebook and you'll see a setting that defaults to "code". Press the error and change the setting to "markdown". After that simply enter the code that you want to make a comment, but don't use the hashtag. Just type it like a normal sentence and then press shift + enter. It'll display the way that you want.